# Custom Sign-In Page Not Executing Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-b2c

Unable to get Javascript to execute on my custom flow's page to modify the page after the injected `api` tag.

When running flows, the latest version `2.1.14` reports a `regex pattern error`, version `2.1.10` and `2.1.1`, do not have the regex issue but the console shows no information or the `log` done. Nor is my simple call done.

How can this be resolved?

---

###### Things Tried

- Page Layout versions tried

  - 2.1.0, 2.1.10, 2.1.14 (last greatest numbered version)
- `Enable JavaScript enforcing page layout` set to `On`
- Tried on Edge and Chrome Browsers

###### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h3 id="demo">Replace Me</h3>
    <div id="api" role="main">
    <script defer>
        console.log("Defer Action");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Jabberwocky!";
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

###### Properties in B2C

[image]

###### Policy XMl

```xml
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="B2CSignUpOrSignInWithPassword_V3" />
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
        <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
      <SessionExpiryType>Rolling</SessionExpiryType>
```

###### Running Test HTML

[image: Running in VSCode, Flow runs 2.1.1 and 2.1.14]

Comment: Did you set the `<UserJourneyBehaviors><ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution></UserJourneyBehaviors>` in the `RelyingParty` element?

Comment: No that has not been set. How/where is that set and what would it resolve in the above situation?

Comment: In your policy XML (e.g. `SignUpOrSignin.xml`): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#enable-javascript

Comment: @SergejChristoforov When I downloaded the policy it had the item already set. I've updated the post showing that xml and the properties of the flow where  enable `JavaScript enforcing page layout` is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please double check your template HTML markup, I believe JavaScript doesn't work because `<div id="api" role="main">` is not closed.

I've tested B2C login with your HTML template and it started working after adding the closing `</div>` tag like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h3 id="demo">Replace Me</h3>
    <div id="api" role="main"></div>
    <script defer>
        console.log("Defer Action");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Jabberwocky!";
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its always the little things.... thx. :-)

Comment: no problem, glad it helped :)